# Cant find jar library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I imported a JAVA project in my Eclipse workspace.

In the "Problams" window it says that the project is missing some required jar libraries, and gives a path which is wrong and not where this jar libraries are located.

The libraries are in my project but in other path.
How can i point to the right path of this required files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project, go to properties, then select java build path, then go to the libraries tab and fix the entries.